# JButton for each row only actionlistener of last button is activated

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Hi i am writing a little application to ping several hosts simultaneously.

As you can see in the picture below i have jtable with a column full of buttons. My **Problem** is following: I add to the whole column the same Button with the same actionListener. If i click on one of the buttons only the actionlistener of the last one is activated and the name is changed to name of the clicked button. WHY?

**The objective** of the button is that the user inserts the IP-Address in the first column and start the pinging via clicking the button. Several pings are now send to the IP-Address to determine its connection. If the user inserts the IP-Address the PingRow object in the tablemodel stores the address correctly. I used objects instead of a two-dimensional array in the tablemodel.

Picture of application

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONrcO.jpg]

The actionlistener for the Button "neue Zeile hinzufügen". Which means "add new Row". The actionlistener instance a PingRow object used in the tablemodel and the JButton for the second column. The action pings the host in its actionlistener. The action should get somehow the correct number of the row or the correct object of the row. In the last two lines i add to the column a CellRenderer and Cell Editor. They are used to render the JButton.

```
public class NewRow implements ActionListener{
JTable table;

Model_Main mMain;
public NewRow(JTable table_Ping, Model_Main MM) {
    table = table_Ping;
    mMain = MM;
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //Get the tablemodel
    PingTableModel modelA = (PingTableModel) table.getModel();
    //JButton definition
    OJButton tmp = new OJButton(table.getRowCount());
    tmp.setText("Starte Ping: " + tmp.getId());
    //Instance a object for the new row
    PingRow pingRowObject = new PingRow("",tmp,0,0,table.getRowCount());
    //Instance the action
    PingAddressAction pingAddressAction = new PingAddressAction(pingRowObject);
    //Add the object to an arraylist
    mMain.getListederPingRows().add(pingRowObject);
    //Add the object to the tablemodel
    modelA.addRow(pingRowObject);
    //Rob Camick Class
    ButtonColumn buttonColumn = new ButtonColumn(table,pingAddressAction,1);
}

}
```

The CellEditor - OJButton is a normal JButton with an additional id for testing purpose; I copied the mouselistener from the tutorial from Mister Camick and added it to the JTable.

```
public class JButtonEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {
OJButton button;
String txt;

public JButtonEditor(OJButton Button, PingRow pingRowObject, JTable table, Action action) {
    super();
    button = Button;
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.addActionListener(e1 -> {
        //TODO: Bug fixen. Wenn man zu schnell eine weitere Zeile hinzufügt wird die gleiche rowcount übergeben.
        int row = table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getEditingRow());
        fireEditingStopped();
        //  Invoke the Action
        ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent(
                table,
                ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,
                "" + row);
        action.actionPerformed(event);
    });
}
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                             boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    txt = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
    button.setText(txt);
    return button;
}


}
```

The Action

```
public class PingAddressAction implements Action {
PingRow pingRowObject;

public PingAddressAction(PingRow pingRowObject) {
    this.pingRowObject = pingRowObject;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Ping_Thread ping_thread = new Ping_Thread(pingRowObject);

    if (ping_thread.isStatus()) {
        ping_thread.start();
    }
}....
```

**Solution**

1. Implement the class from the tutorial: https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/
2. Write an Action like this:

   ```
   public class PingAddressAction implements Action {

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

   JTable table = (JTable) e.getSource();
   PingTableModel modelA = (PingTableModel) table.getModel();
   //Get the row number from the event actioncommand and the object from the tablemodel
   PingRow pingRowObject= modelA.getData(Integer.valueOf(e.getActionCommand()));
   //the object contains all the information from the row
   Ping_Thread ping_thread = new Ping_Thread(pingRowObject);

   if (ping_thread.isStatus()) {
       ping_thread.start();
   }
   }.....
   ```

Comment: If still stuck, a valid [mcve] would help us nicely.

Comment: well yes you are right i will delete the tablemodel and the celleditor Interesting part of code is the first one.

Comment: ???? That's not an MCVE. Please read or re-read the [mcve] link before deleting anything else. Also look at the [sscce](http://sscce.org) link for more on what we need to see.

Comment: Please remove `Solved` from your title, and post the solution you found as a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
aJTable.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
```

Comment: well yes that is the idea with the mouseclickListener. :)

Comment: @AlaskaStack, what MouseListener?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for a better way to implement a JButton as the renderer/editor for a column.

You just need to provide the `Action` to be invoked when the editor for the cell is invoked.

Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some variables are correct other are not. Your code is a mess to read as the forum highlight classes/variables based on Java conventions which you are not following.

Comment: i tried to implement the tips from the tutorial but i still get something wrong and i dont understand it.

Comment: @AlaskaStack, Well the point of the tutorial is to REPLACE (not customize) your renderer/editor with the code from the tutorial. Then you just write the Action.